# How can I access optical drive status information?

Tags: linux, devices, block-device, data-cd

I can obtain the status of a connected display with:
`cat /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/status`

Is there something analogous for optical drives? I looked around in /sys/ but couldn't find anything that looked like device information for the cdrom (sr0) drive.

I want to write a script that determines if the drive is finished copying, to eject the disc, and then copy the contents once a new disc is inserted into the drive.

Answer (score 2):

Minutes after posting this, I found what I was looking for with the help of `sudo lshw`. On this computer, device information for the CD-ROM/DVD-ROM drive is located in `/sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0`. It looks like I can obtain the device status with `cat /sys/bus/scsi/devices/0:0:0:0/device_busy`.

Edit:
I discovered `device_busy` alone is not helpful. The busy bit `1` seems to be set only when the disc is actually active (hence the file name). So, when there is a disc in the drive, and it's not busy, `cat device_busy` returns `0`. I would need additional information to have my script correctly eject the disc when it's not busy. It seems difficult to distinguish between the disc in the drive but not active `0`, and no disc in the drive `0`. I was hoping there would be a file called `drive_status` that output either `ejected` or `not ejected`.

I could grab the exit code of the `cp -rf` command (or `ls` when the drive is open), and use both that and the `device_busy` file to determine when to eject the disc and prompt user to insert a new one. That seems a bit hacky to me, though.

Comment: I found this which is relevant, too: https://superuser.com/questions/630588/how-to-detect-whether-there-is-a-cd-rom-in-the-drive